# Try catch statements with window forms application

Tags: c#

My goal is to throw a NegativeBalanceException if there is an attempt to take the balance below zero. Just like if this was a real bank account. I had if and else statements, but butchered them up and am trying to learn try, catch, and throw statements (was reading on finally as well but I don't think that applies here). Anyway, I set up where a catch statement works if I just hit the deposit button without typing anything. But, I don't understand where it is wanting me to implement it in for taking it below zero. Is it in my deposit method? Or is it in the actual btn_deposit? Also, what is the purpose of using try catch statements over if else statements? I am new to programming and am just trying to learn.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public class BankAccount
    {
        decimal amount = 300.00m;
        // Declare Delegate Type Object
        public delegate void BankDelegate(decimal oldBalance, decimal newBalance);
        // Create Delegate Type Events 
        public event BankDelegate OnDeposit;
        public event BankDelegate OnWithdraw;

        public void Deposit(decimal a)
        {
            {
                if (a > 0)
                {
                OnDeposit(this.amount, this.amount + a);
                this.amount += a;
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No!");
                }
            }
        }
        public void Withdraw(decimal a)
        {
            // Fire OnWithdraw Event and pass old and new balance amount
            OnWithdraw(this.amount, this.amount - a);
            this.amount -= a;
        }
    }
    // Declare BankAccount class variable 
    BankAccount account = null;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        account = new BankAccount();
        // Attach Event Handlers with Events     
        account.OnDeposit += new BankAccount.BankDelegate(account_OnDeposit);
        account.OnWithdraw += new BankAccount.BankDelegate(account_OnWithdraw);
    }
    private void btnDeposit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
                account.Deposit(Convert.ToDecimal(textBox1.Text));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    private void btnWIthdraw_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        account.Withdraw(Convert.ToDecimal(textBox1.Text));
    }
    void account_OnDeposit(decimal oldBalance, decimal newBalance)
    {
        label4.Text = oldBalance.ToString();
        label5.Text = newBalance.ToString();
    }
    void account_OnWithdraw(decimal oldBalance, decimal newBalance)
    {
        label4.Text = oldBalance.ToString();
        label5.Text = newBalance.ToString();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Unrelated to the actual question, but related to the domain: accounts are actual accounts of activity, not a single number. Use a list of transactions rather than a single balance that is updated.

Comment: I would HIGHLY HIGHLY recommend reading [Eric Lippert’s Blog - Vexing exceptions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx).  You can bet you'll get a really good answer about exceptions there as Eric Lippert was the principal developer on the C# compiler team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only throw exceptions for exceptional circumstances. Overdrawn accounts are not an exceptional circumstance.. but depositing a negative amount is.

Therefore, I would do something like this for the `Deposit` method:

```
public void Deposit(decimal a)
{
    if (a < 1)
        throw new NegativeDepositException("You cannot deposit this amount");

    OnDeposit(this.amount, this.amount + a);
    this.amount += a;
}
```

**BUT**.

You should be validating this prior to entering the method. That way, the exception should never be called - unless you call `Deposit` from another method without the check - which would be exceptional.

```
private void btnDeposit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // try..catch removed. This will now crash if you forget to check the value.
    var amount = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox1.Text);
    if (amount < 1)
        MessageBox.Show("You cannot deposit this amount");
    else
        account.Deposit(amount);
}
```

Also, I would change `Withdraw` to return `bool`, since overdrawing is not really an exceptional circumstance:

```
public bool Withdraw(decimal a) 
{
    if (this.amount - a >= 0)
    {
        // Fire OnWithdraw Event and pass old and new balance amount
        OnWithdraw(this.amount, this.amount - a);
        this.amount -= a;
        return true; // successful
    }
    else
    {
        return false; // unsuccessful
    }
}
```

Then when you call it:

```
private void btnWIthdraw_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!account.Withdraw(Convert.ToDecimal(textBox1.Text)))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Insufficient funds");
    }
}
```

EDIT:

In response to your comment. You must create your own exception class if you want it to be named a specific way (or if you want it to extend the functionality of a normal `Exception`). In my example, you would have to create this:

```
public class NegativeDepositException : Exception {
}
```

Thats it. It gets everything it needs from `Exception`.. for now.

Comment: it is saying that 'NegativeDepositException' could not be found. I am assuming I need to add something in my System. at the top? I could be entirely wrong. Also, what is the purpose of really using these? I used if/else forever until I started seeing most sophisticated programs using this? Teaching myself this is difficult.

Comment: You must create your own exception class that inherits from `Exception`. I will update my post to show you this. Also, exceptions are as I said.. used to create faults in your application for exceptional circumstances. If the error isn't exceptional.. don't throw an exception. Use if/else instead.

Comment: What classifies something as being exceptional and not being exceptional? That seems more like something of what is someones personal opinion? Are there any "norms" of what classifies this case?

Comment: The norms are whatever your domain expects. Does your domain expect that people will deposit a negative balance? Well, no. If you go to a bank right now and ask to deposit negative $50 they will laugh.. it is an exceptional request. Now, if you ask to Withdraw $50.. that's completely different. If your bank allows overdrawn accounts.. then its entirely possible that people are allowed to withdraw $60 when they only have $50 in their account. This is expected.. and isn't an exceptional request.